# How to check the result of the pattern validation for a text input in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text input with a custom oninvalid message:

```
<input id="foo" type="text" maxlength="16" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter letters and / 
or numbers only.')" onBlur="chk()" autofocus>
```

In the onBlur event I want to run some code, but only if the text entered passed the pattern validation specified.  Something like:

```
function chk() {
    if (document.getElementById("foo").isvalid?()) {
        bar(); 
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
function chk() {
    if ($("#foo").isvalid?()) {
        bar(); 
    }
}
```

**Update**

I found the following solution, but it does repeat the code of the pattern validation:

```
function chk() {
    var exp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
    if (exp.test($("#foo").val())) {
        bar(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually i always use onChange event.

Comment: You ask 3 different questions in your title and throughout your post - which are you really asking?

Comment: OK, I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the pattern from your input but we need to modify it slightly. As [MDN explains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern): "the pattern pattern must match the entire value, not just some subset." This basically boils down to the browser implicitly prepending a `^` and appending a `$` to the pattern value. So, for our case, when we grab that string pattern value from our input, we also need to do the same to match the browser's functionality:

```
function chk() {
  var pattern = $("#foo").attr('pattern');
  var exp = new RegExp('^' + pattern + '$');
  if (exp.test($("#foo").val())) {
    bar(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Your code this.getAttribute does not work, so I used $("#foo").attr("pattern") instead.  Other than that I would tick your answer.

Comment: @tyebillion Oh yeah, forgot we were using jQuery. Fixed the answer!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to recheck if the text matches the regular expression manually. You can just check the [ValidityState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState).

```
function chk() {
    if ($("#foo").validity.valid) {
        bar(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do note that `validity`, as well as the implicit `pattern`, does not inherently work on older browsers and may not be considered fully compatible with a global audience.

Comment: The jQuery condition here wont work, instead you should use `$("#foo").prop('validity')?.valid`

Answer (score 1):

you can check [onChange event](https://api.jquery.com/change/#change-handler) and call that method everytime an input is changed

Comment: No, I only want to check when the user leaves the input.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you want to create a regex with the pattern attribute you set in your input :

```
function chk() {

     var pattern = this.getAttribute('pattern');
     var regex = new RegExp(pattern);

     // ...  
}
```

and then verify if the input value match the regex :

```
function chk() {

     var pattern = this.getAttribute('pattern');
     var regex = new RegExp(pattern);

     // regex matching
     if (regex.test(this.value)) {
       bar();
     }

}
```

see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t6wLeqq0/1/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't always work, for example try an input x-

Comment: yeah that's because the pattern you provide match as soon as one character is a number or a letter, you can try it on https://regex101.com/

Comment: Well that is not an acceptable solution as I want the same functionality as offered by the pattern attribute.  I used test instead on the regex and it worked fine, see my update section above!

Comment: yeah I can understand, you should look at Alvaro's answer

Comment: When I Google "jquery validity" all I get are links about a plug in of that name.  It seems ridiculous to use a plug in for the sake of two lines of code, at least in my case.

Comment: This is not true, you can see my answer as to why this is incorrect functionality.

Comment: check this for pattern attribute: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html5-form-validation-with-the-pattern-attribute--cms-25145

Comment: @rgthree Yes, my mistake, validity is not related to a plugin: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation_api.asp